Microsoft Fabric Limitations
I am working on Microsoft Fabric but noted few limitations. I just want to confirm do we have any workarounds any soon updaes from Microsoft on these problems -

Connection information like server, database name,credentials (e.g. with on prim SQL server) can't be dynamic. Currently only Lakehouse,Datawarehouse and KSQL is supporting dynamic connections.

2.Keyvault is not integrated with connections like how we can use it in Linkedservices in ADF. Either we have to give Basic or Windows authentication
3.Event trigger which is in preview is supporting only ADLS gen 2 not even Onelake folders
4.Notebooks can't be nested in folders. Like create one parent folder and added related notebooks within it like Databricks.
Please can we confirm these limitations and if any idea about workaround or updates from Microsoft side.
I want to confirm Limitations for Microsoft Fabric

Can you provide information about your requirement? any errors or blockers?
